# How to copy all files with same extension between identical directory structures?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, shell, directory-structure

I have 2 independent folders A and B. B has many files with the extension `.build`. Across A there are a fe subdirectories that have the same structure as subdirectories of B.

For example A has `some_path/Tools/Camera/` and B has `different_path/Tools/Camera`. Say I manually identified 2 subdirectories one in A one in B that have the same structure, I need to copy all .build files from the subdir of B into the one in A.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the `globstar` Bash shell option: `shopt -s globstar`

Now change directory into B and run:

```
for path in **/; do
    [ -d "<A-dir>/$path" ] && cp -n "$path/"*.build "<A-dir>/$path"
done
```

This will recursively check each subdirectory in B and see if there is an equivalent subdirectory in A. If there is then it will copy all `.build` files from the B subdirectory over to A.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.

Here's one that comes to mind.

```
cd different_path
find . -iname '*.build' | while read filename ; do 
    cp -n "$filename" "some_path/${filename#./}" 
done
```

If there's any chance you have some poorly named files with linebreaks in their names or similar, you might instead use a null separator:

```
cd different_path
find . -iname '*.build' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename ; do 
    cp -n "$filename" "some_path/${filename#./}" 
done
```

Comment: You may want to read [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Seems like fussiness to me, but I'll add a suggestion using a null separator.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -C 'A/(**/)(*.build)' 'B/$1$2'
```

If the corresponding subdirectories are not guaranteed to exist in `B`, you can change it to:

```
mkdcp() { mkdir -p -- $2:h && cp -- "$@"; }
zmv -P mkdcp 'A/(**/)(*.build)' 'B/$1$2'
```

Where `zmv` uses our `mkdcp` function instead of `cp` (with `-C`) to copy the files.